# Finite group $G$ has $61$ Sylow $3$-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Suppose that the finite group $G$ has $61$ Sylow $3$-subgroups. Then I want to prove that there exist two Sylow $3$-subgroups $P$ and $Q$ satisfying  $|P: P\cap Q|=3 $.

Since $n_{3}=61$, then the order of $G$ must be $61.3^{n}.p_{1}^{a_{1}}\dots p_{k}^{a_{k}}$. But I couldn't connect with $61$ to show the existence of $P$ and $Q$ with the desired feature.
What should I look at first to prove this claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the conjugation action of a Sylow $3$-subgroup $P$ on the set of all Sylow $3$-subgroups.

There is one fixed point, namely $P$ itself, and the other orbits have length $3^k$ for some $k>0$.

Since $60$ is not divisible by $9$, the remaining orbits cannot all have length divisible by $9$, and so there must be at least one orbit of length $3$. Let $Q$ be in such an orbit. Then the stabilizer of $Q$ in $P$ is $N_P(Q) = P \cap Q$. So $|P:P \cap Q|=3$.

Comment: Why did you consider mod 9 ? And also 60 is not equivalent to 3 mod 9. Unfortunately I couldn't understand the rest. Is it possible to explain in more detail?

Comment: Sorry, $60 \equiv 6 \bmod 9$, but the argument still work. The point is that $60$ is not divisible by 9, so the nontrivial orbits cannot all have length divisible by 9, and so at least one of them has length  3.